# How to integrate PayPal in JSF application

Tags: jsf, paypal, seam

I have to integrate Paypal with JSF/Seam. Is there any good tutorial out there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to consult their developer documentation. I've never done it for Java, but a good couple of years back I did it for PHP. I still recall very good that they have had excellent code examples in their developer documentation which I could just copypaste and just alter slightly in order to get it to work. They had examples for Java/JSP as well (which in turn should easily be portable to JSF). Access to developer documentation only requires a Paypal customer account (which I don't have right now). Contact if necessary your customer for login details. Then you'll be able to access their developer documentation as well.